# Is there a language made specifically for Entity Component programming?

Tags: oop, functional-programming, entity-system, component-based

I know there are languages for functional programming (LISP, Haskell, etc.) and OOP programming (Java, C#, Ruby, Python, many more), but are there any that are made around the concept of Entity Component Programming?

Answer (score 1):

I'm in no way an expert on `entity component` development, but after skimming through both of these articles:

- [Article on GamaSutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/MeganFox/20101208/6590/Game_Engines_101_The_EntityComponent_Model.php)
- [Why use an entity system framework for game development?](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/why-use-an-entity-framework)

It seems to me that an `entity` is just something that stores data, and then you do operations on that data. Assuming that I'm correct in my understanding this means that you can choose any almost any language you want. But `entity component` programming in and of itself does not use objects, which might make high-level languages like C#, Java and even C++ overkill. However I'd think that C or Go would be perfect languages for this type of programming because then you could define `structs` and `methods` that operate on those structs. I'd go with Go only because it's sexier.

Now I haven't answered your question, but from my research all I could find was this language which I have no idea if it is openly available or not:

[ComponentJ article](http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/1820-0214/2008/1820-02140802063S.pdf)

I think it would be easier to just use a framework for one of the popular languages instead.